# node js создание ярлыка папки

Tags: node.js, windows, path, filestream, fs

Всем привет! Пишу приложение на node.js и встал вопрос создания папки в директории с проектом, и создание ярлыка этой папки на рабочем столе. С созданием папки проблем не возникает, но как можно создать ярлык в node.js мне не понятно. Заранее большое спасибо!